# how to visualize high volumn 3 dimensional data

Tags: python, r, plot, pandas, data-visualization

I have a data set like the following:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
mypos = np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 2))
mydata = DataFrame(mypos, columns=['x', 'y'])
myres = np.random.rand(100, 1)
mydata['res'] = myres
```

The res variable is continous, the x and y variables are integers representing
positions (therefore largely repetitive),
and res represents kind of correlations between pairs of positions.

I am wondering what are the best ways of visualizing this data set?
Possible approaches already considered:

1. Scatter plot, with the res variable visualized by a color gradient.
2. Parallel coordinates plot.

The first approach is problematic when the number of positions get large,
because high values (which are the values we care about) of the res variable would be drowned in a sea of
small dots.

The second approach could be promising, but I am having trouble producing it.
I have tried the parallel_coordinates function from the pandas module,
but it's not behaving as I would like it to. (see this question here:
[parallel coordinates plot for continous data in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547347/parallel-coordinates-plot-for-continous-data-in-pandas)
)

Comment: Should this be tagged with "r"? Seems like it's more of a Python Q.

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't mind doing it in R, as long as it can get the job done.

Comment: pairwise hexbin plots?

Comment: That is too "blurry".

Comment: `parcoord` or `parallelplot` work for me in R. Using transparent colors helps when there are thousands of rows. Maybe you should repost with data creation having already been done. Then it would be coding question rather than an a "recommend a method question."

Comment: Which packages are they in?

Comment: You are just adding column... How is it 3d data?

Comment: Every observation has 3 vars, that's 3D.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps to find a solution in R. Good luck.

```
# you need this package for the colour palette
library(RColorBrewer)

# create the random data
dd <- data.frame(
    x = round(runif(100, 0, 10), 0),
    y = round(runif(100, 0, 10), 0),
    res = runif(100)
)

# pick the number of colours (granularity of colour scale)
nColors <- 100 

# create the colour pallete
cols <-colorRampPalette(colors=c("white","blue"))(nColors)

# get a zScale for the colours
zScale <- seq(min(dd$res), max(dd$res), length.out = nColors)

# function that returns the nearest colour given a value of res
findNearestColour <- function(x) {
    colorIndex <- which(abs(zScale - x) == min(abs(zScale - x)))
    return(cols[colorIndex])
}

# the first plot is the scatterplot
### this has problems because points come out on top of eachother
plot(y ~ x, dd, type = "n")
for(i in 1:dim(dd)[1]){
    with(dd[i,],
        points(y ~ x, col = findNearestColour(res), pch = 19)
    )
}

# this is your parallel coordinates plot (a little better)
plot(1, 1, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(min(dd$x, dd$y), max(dd$x, dd$y)), 
     type = "n", axes = F, ylab = "", xlab = "")
for(i in 1:dim(dd)[1]){
    with(dd[i,],
        segments(0, x, 1, y, col = findNearestColour(res))
    )
}
```